# How can I assign different values to x and y by using a loop (not by user) in PHP + SVG

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop, svg

I am making Gantt chart, using PHP+SVG, for a PHP-Chart Library similar to http://www.goat1000.com/. In my code I have a problem i want to assign a different value to "x" and "y" by looping. In the following code I am assigning value "x" and "y" by user values that is wrong according to my requirements, please suggest how can I assign different values to x and y by using a loop so that next bars locate after previous bars as shown in following figure:

http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/Gantt-chart

One bar can't be positioned on another bar, bars position should change on each value.

Here is my code:

class GanttChart extends Graph{

```
function Draw()
{
    $width = 300; // canvas size
    $height = 400;  
    $value =$this->GetValues();   
    $data=$this->values; 
    $max = count($data); 


    $w=$width; // canvas size
    $h=$height;
    $a="<svg width=\"$w\" height=\"$h\">";


    $sum=array_sum($data);
    $colours = array('yellow','black','red','pink','grey','purple');
    for ($i = 0; $i<$max; $i=$i+1) {

        $a.= "<rect x=\"$value[$i]\" y=\"$value[$i]\" width=\"20\" height=\"$value[$i]\"  style=\"stroke: black; fill:red;\"/>";
        //$a.= "  <circle cx=\"$value[$i]\" cy=\"$value[$i]\" r=\"15\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"red\" />";

    }
    $a.="</svg>";
    return  $a;
    //echo PieGraph();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$value` is an array and you want the `$i`'th element in that string, [you can do](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

```
$a.= "<rect x=\"{$value[$i]}\" y=\"{$value[$i]}\" ...
```

or use [string concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$a.= "<rect x=\"".$value[$i]."\" y=\"".$value[$i]."\" ...
```